# RenderAction from OtherArea in MVC 2.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

How Can i use renderaction to render an action from inner Area in ASP.NET MVC 2.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<% Html.RenderAction("ActionName", "ControllerName", new {area="AreaName"}); %>`